# Calling Futurebuilder efficiently

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 3 Future builders in my Stateless widget. They each return a list.

For each list, the data is coming from 1 external Rest calls thus adds up to 3 rest calls.

On average, it takes about 800ms for each rest call to return a response.

That means 800ms x 3 (2 seconds +) time is taken to fill up my page which is not ideal.

I want to just make a single call (which I can do from backend) which will hold data for all 3 FutureBuilders.

I will then extract relevant data for all widgets from there. But how can I do this?

Cos the future parameter in the FutureBuilder is expecting the Future call to some

method for each FutureBuilder. I can't just pass in this new Rest call which fetches data for all in

a single call and repeat it 3 times in each FutureBuilder. That would be pointless. Is there a way

around for this?

Please note that I am looking to avoid turning this into a Stateful Widget. Thank you.

As you can see in the following, I making 3x rest calls.

```
restService.restCallOne(), 
restService.restCallTwo(), 
restService.restCallThree().
```

Instead I want to make a single rest call like restService.SingleCall() and use it fill data accordingly. Or welcome any other alternative solutions. Cos as it stands, it takes me 2 seconds plus overall to draw UI. Looking to bring it down to 800ms or less.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {

  final RestService restService = RestService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: restService.restCallOne(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return // some widget which extracts relevant data from rest call data and draws the UI
                    },
                );
            },
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: restService.restCallTwo(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return // some widget which extracts relevant data from rest call data and draws the UI
                  },
                );
            },
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: restService.restCallThree(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return // some widget which extracts relevant data from rest call data and draws the UI
                  },
                );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

P.S

Sniffing through docs for info but would be great if someone could advice if these rest calls gonna happen sequentially for each FutureBuilder, thus meaning it takes 2 seconds plus (looks like it from what I experience for the UI to fill up) or do they happen in async?

=========================================================

**Updated:**

Adding following to show how the full ListView is constructed.

As mentioned there are going to be 3x lists, each within it's own future builder currently.

When I said 60 images, I meant each list will load up about 20 low res image.

In above FutureBuilders, the part where I have commented the following:

```
return // some widget which extracts relevant data
```

I return the following widget in that part which takes in an image url from that rest call and constructs an image. Thus for each list, this widget gets constructed 20 times X 3 list = 60 low res images.

```
class SideScrollImage extends StatelessWidget {

  final String link;
  final int id;

  const SideScrollImage({this.link, this.id});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print('image id is ${this.id}');
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ShowPage(movies[0])),);
        },
        child: Image(
          image: NetworkImage(link),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And this is the rest call.

```
class RestService {

  Dio _dio = Dio();

  Future<dynamic> restCallOne() async {
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch()..start();
    Response response = await _dio.get('endpoint that takes 100ms from postman and 800ms based on this stopwatch output');
    print('getFeatureTrendingData() executed in ${stopwatch.elapsed.inMilliseconds} ms');
    return response.data;
  }
}
```

The display will turn out something like the following, with 3 horizontally scrollable list of images.

[image]

Comment: if you use `Future.wait([restService.restCallOne(), 
restService.restCallTwo(), 
restService.restCallThree()]);` then you can have one `FutureBuilder` (or i miss something and it is not what you really want)

Comment: @pskink Roughly do get what you mean. Ultimately I need 3x lists. Guess I could use 1x FutureBuilder to get relevant data and build 3x lists from it probably putting them into a column to get children instead of child.

Comment: your `snapshot.data` will contain a `List` with 3 results, so `snapshot.data[0]` will have a result of `restService.restCallOne()` ets - for example try `Future.wait([Future.delayed(1.seconds, () => 'foo'), Future.wait([Future.delayed(3.seconds, () => 'bar')]).then(print);`

Comment: of course i meant:  `Future.wait([Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => 'foo'), Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => 'bar')]).then(print);`

Comment: @pskink Thanks. Played around with the above suggestion. The time taken is still like 8 seconds and sometimes more. Its crazy that the backend service returns the response within 100ms (via curl or postman). But on the flutter app it takes 800ms per query plus there are image links in the response which seems to take even longer to draw out. About 60 low res images. Wondering how Netflix pulls it off on their home page showing so much images in reasonable time. But not a related question here.

Comment: is it possible to post `restCallOne` code for example?

Comment: btw now you say that your `ListView.children` array does not have 3 items but 60?  did i get you right? if so, cannot you use `ListView.builder`?

Comment: @pskink I've updated the question above. Look under Updated: Clarified what I meant plus a screenshot to showcase what I mean. Also added the Rest call.

Comment: ok now it  gives the better view...one more thing,  i wonder how you measure those 8 seconds? if one rest call is max 800ms... so all 3 are 8 secs? how come? tried to call them one by one (`Future.forEach` for example)?

Comment: @pskink So there are 3 separate rest calls, each taking about 800ms which amounts to about 2.4 seconds. From the rest call, now I am trying to fetch all those images and construct the individual widgets. Each call to fetch the image takes approx 40ms. This adds up to another 2.4 seconds (40ms x 60). Total 4.8 seconds for everything to get drawn on the page. This is best case scenario. The time taken fluctuates thus it does goes up to 8 seconds. I'd say average is more around 6 seconds in total. Not tried Future.forEach yet, will give it a go.

Comment: *"From the rest call, now I am trying to fetch all those images and construct the individual widgets"* - wait, wait, wait, i think i am lost now, this is what `NetworkImage` is doing...

Comment: @pskink Yup, rest call fetched all the 60 image urls. Now I pass in those image url to NetworkImage each time to get the image.

Comment: ok so why you have 40ms * 60? you have `NetworkImage` lazily build by `ListView.builder` and your sample image shows that you have only 12 items visible at time (3 rows x 4 cols), so where does 60 come from?